# What does a number argument in printf without quotes do?

Tags: c, arguments, printf

What does a number argument in `printf` without quotes do?

e.g. `printf( 3 + "goodbye");` results in output dbye.  Why do I get this output?

Comment: this is just code obfuscation that serves nothing else. where did you find such a garbage?

Comment: was just going through some net links. True it wont be used anywhere other than dumb mcq tests.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`3 + "goodbye"` is equivalent to `&"goodbye"[3]` - in other words it's just a pointer to the fourth element of "goodbye" and so your example will print "dbye".

Answer (score 0):

That is not a "number argument to `printf()`", really.The function being called is just getting a single pointer argument, as usual (the first argument to `printf()` is the format string pointer.

You're simply using pointer arithmetic to increase the pointer to the string `"goodbye"` with 3 characters, in effect skipping the first three characters and thus getting the remainder `"dbye"` as the argument.